# Table Column to hyperlink

Tags: php, html

I currently have php generating a table from csv. I use  tags to identify columns, which i later use jquery and datatables to sort, filter, and highlight.

I am looking for a way to make the data from a column into links. the data is case numbers and there is a predefinited link, you would just added the case number to the end of it and that would be your link to another page.

Do anyone know how I can achieve this, I'll include a snippet below so you can get an idea of how the table is created.

```
<th>ASUP Created Flag</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


END;

//here we open the csv file as read-only
$f = fopen("cases.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
//this starts the alternation of tr and td for building the table        
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
//after the table has been built, this is where we close it out
echo "\n</tbody></table></section></div></body></html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking for something like:

```
<th><a href="some url">ASUP Created Flag</a></th>
```

or for the actual cell data:

```
foreach ($line as $cell) {
    echo "<td><a href='some url'>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</a></td>";
}
```

If you're wondering what `some url` should be, well that's completely up to you.  If it depends on the cell data, then you would need some way to reference a URL given the cell data (either through a lookup array, database table, just some way to associate a URL with the value in `$cell`).

**Update**

If you want your case numbers to be links, and the value of the cell is the exact value you want to use in the URL, you can do something like this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($line as $cell) {
    $cell = htmlspecialchars($cell);
    if($count == 0) {
        echo "<td><a href='/case/" . $cell . "'>" . $cell . "</a></td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>" . $cell . "</td>";
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to specify one column. I have no clue how to do that. I speculate maybe javascript after the php generates the table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... there is a single column in your CSV file that you want to add a link to? And is that link going to appear on the column header or the cell data?

Comment: currently i have it generating multiple columns and rows. each column has a table header. I want all the rows for a specific column to be links. heres a screenshot of my table (part of the case numbers has been cut out) http://imgur.com/6c6HOsa I want to turn the case numbers into links

Comment: @hackerseraph I've updated my answer.  Let me know if that works for you